# Green Screen Video to Transparent PNG's

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for way to extract frames from a video shot in front of a green screen. This is the source video, so nothing has been chroma keyed on to it yet. I want to save the frames as PNGs with the green replaced by transparent.

I see its possible to get transparent video based [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/21397/green-screen-to-transparent-with-ffmpeg), but I am looking to save as transparent PNG's, not video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are satisfied with the chroma key quality from ffmpeg, it's just

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf chromakey={...} -vsync 0 out%d.png
```

where `{...}` is replaced with your [`chromakey`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#chromakey) filter arguments.